# What does this Orleans message mean: Dropping expired message Request

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, orleans

We are running into some issues for our Microsoft Orleans.

The error message is:

> Dropping expired message Request [S172.18.0.28:11111:65729425
> documentstate/105-ACTIVE-ACTIVE!5487.1]->[S172.18.0.28:11111:65729425
> documentwork/105-ACTIVE-ACTIVE!5487.1]

What does it mean?

Experts explain to me the meaning of this message.

Comment: See Client Drop Timeout : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/orleans.configuration.silomessagingoptions?view=orleans-7.0#properties

Answer (score 1):

In Orleans, messages between grains can have a specified **lifetime**, and if a message doesn't get processed within that time frame (perhaps due to **network latency**, a backlog of messages on the server, or the grain being **deactivated**), the system will drop the message to prevent outdated or irrelevant messages from being processed.

you might need to look into the following:

- **Check your network latency**: High latency might cause messages to take
  longer than expected to reach their destination.
- **Review grain activation and deactivation settings**: If grains are
  deactivating too quickly, they might not be available to process
  incoming messages.
- **Adjust message timeout settings**: If your application's workload
  typically includes long-running tasks, you might need to increase the
  timeout value for messages.
- **Monitor system performance**: If the system is under heavy load,
  message processing might be delayed. Optimizing performance or
  scaling out might be necessary.
- **Review the Orleans logs and metrics**: These can provide more context
  about why messages are expiring and help you pinpoint the bottleneck
  or misconfiguration causing the issue.

It's important to carefully consider the implications of increasing timeouts or altering grain lifecycle settings, as these can affect the performance and reliability of your Orleans application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I have another question: why same drop expired message happen again and again? Why does Orleans even try to call the function again and again? Does that mean that the grain is destroyed? for example:  this message: Dropping expired message Status Response [S172.18.0.28:11111:65794526 documentstate/105-ACTIVE-ACTIVE!14798.1]->[S172.18.0.28:11111:65794526 sys.client/hosted-172.18.0.28:11111@65794526] IsExecuting: False, IsWaiting: True, Diagnostics: [[Activation: S172.18.0.28:11111:65794526/documentstate/105-ACTIVE-ACTIVE!14798.1@1e564658d85247d8989ba2

Comment: One more question: any information about how to read Message: Status Response?